# I keep receiving the error in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, variables

I keep receiving the error in eclipse:

> Syntax error, insert "... VariableDeclaratorId" to complete
>   FormalParameterList  on line 1 at (registered),

might be an easy answer here but I am failing to see it. Thanks in advance.

```
public static void setRegistered(registered) {
    Character.registered = registered;
```

Comment: omg just as i hit ask it came to me to add    public static void setRegistered(boolean registered) {
  Character.registered = registered;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to change

```
public static void setRegistered(registered) {
```

to

```
public static void setRegistered(boolean registered) {
```